# How to fix fustrum cut while zooming using glScalef in QGLWidget

Tags: c++, opengl, qglwidget

I'm working on a simple image viewer using QGLWidget by drawing two triangles and then render them with a texture.

The program allows users to zoom the image by scroll down/up then it changes the zoom factor using glScalef.

so far it works great except I'm encountering a problem where my view frustum is cut.

here's my code

```
void GLWidget::paintGL() 
{
    // scrollOffset has the coordinates of horizontal and vertical scrollbars   
    glViewport(0 - scrollOffset.x(), 0 + scrollOffset.y(), this->width(),  this->height()); 

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, this->width(),  this->height(),  0);  // flip the y axis
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();

    // zooming, error happens when the factor is above 3.0 
    glScalef(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    // Draw something...
}
```

And the screenshot, the error usually happens when the scaling factor is quite big (above 3.0/4.0)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If its not required, don't scale the Z axis.

Change:

`glScalef(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, zoomFactor);`

to

`glScalef(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, 1.0f);`